# Ubuntu volume is corrupt but it works on Windows

Tags: dual-boot, data-corruption

I'm trying to install ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10.

My PC has 1 SSD where Windows is located and another hard disk where I want to create a partition for Ubuntu. It worked one time but during the installation the power went off and now I can't find the disk anymore on Ubuntu. When I try to install Ubuntu, my D Volume (the 1 TB hard disk) doesn't popup. I tried using `ntfsfix` on it but it says:

[image: ntfsfix output]

I tried to run `chkdsk` on Windows on the Volume and there are no errors. I even tried to use gparted and check the disk and it shows:

[image: gparted output]

Comment: Do you have fast-boot or hibernate enabled/active?   If it is, the volume maybe corrupt when windows is hibernated/off because part of the file-system is stored in the windows *fastboot* file, thus any other OS will detect an *unclean* file-system as Ubuntu is reporting.

Comment: @guiverc No, they're both disabled

Comment: What happens if you boot again from the Ubuntu USB drive? Please check carefully, that you can identify the drives, and that you *know* which is the SSD and the HDD in the output of the Linux software tools. If it boots, run **`lsblk`** from a terminal window. If you can see the HDD, chances are that you can use the graphical tool **gparted** and create a partition table and an `ext4` file system on the HDD where you want Ubuntu. Then you can try to install Ubuntu.